# How do I schedule a task to run every x hours using cron? Discord.py

Tags: cron, discord, discord.py

Basically, what I want to do is use the package **aiocron** to schedule an automatic reboot every 5-8 hours because I've noticed some tasks just stop functioning after a certain amount of time being online. I don't know why they stop but they do, I'm not getting any errors either, weirdly enough. If you want the code to the task I'm talking about, here it is:

```py
@tasks.loop(count=None, minutes=2.5)
async def autoh(self):
    await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
    with open("autoposting.json", 'r') as f:
        auto = json.load(f)

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Enjoy your poggers porn lmao",
                                description=f"Posting can be slow, please take into consideration how many servers this bot is in and how many are using auto posting. Please be patient. If I completely stop posting, please rerun the command or join the support server.\n[Add me]({Invite}) | [Join the server]({Server}) | [Vote]({Vote})", colour=EMBED_COLOUR)
        try:
            embed.set_image(url=(await self.get_hentai_img()))
        except nekos.errors.NothingFound:
            return print("no image found")
        else:
            for entry in auto.items():
                if "hentai_channel" in entry[1]:
                    channel = self.bot.get_channel(
                        entry[1]["hentai_channel"])
                    await asyncio.sleep(2)
                    if channel != None:
                        if not channel.is_nsfw():
                            await channel.send(f"This channel seems to not be NSFW anymore.\nThis message will continually repeat until you fix this issue.")
                        else:
                            try:
                                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                            except discord.Forbidden:
                                #pass
                                await channel.guild.owner.send(f"I was unable to autopost due to missing permissions in {channel.guild.name}, please check that the channel still exists and that I have the permission to post to it.\nThis message will continually repeat until you fix the issue at hand.")
```

Comment: What's your question here exactly?

Comment: Basically, what I want to do is use the package aiocron to schedule an automatic reboot every 5-8 hours
I have the code for the reboot, i just have no idea how to use cron
sorry if that was confusing, i kinda got off on a tangent